# how to detect the pause image load address when change kubernetes containerd config

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

I am trying to override the kubernetes system default kubernetes pause image address with file `/etc/containerd/config.toml` like this:

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  sandbox_image = "k8s.m.daocloud.io/pause:3.6"
```

then restart the containerd like this:

```
systemctl restart containerd
```

how to make sure the new pauase pull address works? the kubelet garbage collection will no longer pure the pause image anymore?